# Is this Markov chain recurrent or transient?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, ergodic-theory

A Markov chain $X_n$ $(n\ge1)$ with state space S=0,1,2,3,... has the following transition probabilities:

$$p_{i,i+1}=\frac{(i+1)^2}{2i^2+2i+1},\ p_{i,i-1}=\frac{i^2}{2i^2+2i+1}, \ p_{0,1}=1, \ and \ i\ge 1$$

I am trying to find if it is recurrent or transient. What I have is the following:

Obviously, $p_{i,i+1}$ and $p_{i,i-1}$ depends on $i$, it means that each state will have a different probability. For example, when $i=1$, then $p_{1,2}=4/5$ and $p_{1,0}=1/5$. So, it seems that $p_{i,i+1}$ is decreasing as $p_{i,i-1}$ increases on each step.

$$T=\pmatrix{0&1&0&0&...&0&0&0\\1/5&0&4/5&0&...&0&0&0\\0&4/13&0&9/13&...&0&0&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&0&0&...&1/2&0&1/2}_{nxn}$$

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Markov_chain), a state i is recurrent if and only if the expected number of visits to i is infinite:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}p_{ii}^{(n)}=\infty\\ p_{ii}=Pr(X_n=i|X_0=0)\ for\ n\ge 1$$

for a recurrent state i, the mean hitting time is defined as:

$$M_i=E\left[ T_i \right]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nf_{ii}^{(n)}$$

State i is positive recurrent (or non-null persistent) if Mi is finite; otherwise, state i is null recurrent (or null persistent).

If this Markov chain had a finite state space:

> I think that I should be positive recurrent because it is possible to
> get to any state from any state.

**How does the infinite state space change this fact? I haven't found good information about it.**

What about this?

> If we start from zero, it seems that the MC may return to zero almost surely with probability 1.

Thank you!

Comment: If there were only finitely many states, this would indeed be recurrent because 
it is possible to get from any state to any other state.  However, here we have 
an infinite state space, and it is not at all obvious that the $X_n$ won't 
almost surely go off
to $+\infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I see, so it is transient. So the probability of return to zero must be zero, what do you think? Thank you

Comment: @HuangDawei Have you seen the simple random walk in $1$ dimensions? Is that recurrent or transient? Compare the transition probabilities of that chain, with this chain, for *large* $i$. This will tell you whether to *expect* recurrence or not.

Comment: @HuangDawei No, you can't just say "so it is transient".  It''s not at all obvious whether it is transient or not.

Comment: Of course, I will use the argument of 1D asymmetric random walk for large i because $p_{i,i+1}$ is different of $p_{i,i-1}$. Thank you!

Comment: if it were me, I'd set state zero to be an absorbing state, call the associated matrix $P$ and try to solve for $P\mathbf x = \mathbf x$ where $x_0:=1$ and $x_i \geq 0$ but $\mathbf x\not\propto \mathbf 1$.  If you find a (bounded) solution with all $x_i \in [0,1)$ then it is transient.  If you find an unbounded solution, you can use martingale arguments to show recurrent.  Given the simplicity of the chain, I don't think this needs to be solved explicitly, just show any non-constant solution is (un?)bounded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapting my answer from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3964385/positive-recurrent-null-recurrent-or-transient-prove-of-0-1-markov-chain/3964655#3964655), which asks basically the same question.

---

Let $h_n=\mathbb P_n(\text{hit }0)$, so $h_0=1$. Then
$$h_n=p_{n,n-1}h_{n-1}+p_{n,n+1}h_{n+1}\implies \frac{h_{n+1}-h_n}{h_n-h_{n-1}}=\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}.$$
Telescoping, we get $h_{n+1}-h_n=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}(h_1-h_0)$. So summing over $0\leq n\leq m-1$, we obtain $$h_m=1+(h_1-1)\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{k^2}.$$
As $\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{k^2}\to\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, the fact that $(h_m)_{m=0}^\infty$ is the smallest non-negative solution to this equation implies that $h_1=1-\frac{6}{\pi^2}<1$. This is enough to show that the chain is transient.

Comment: Thank you so much