# positive recurrent, null recurrent, or transient.prove of 0-1 markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Let $\left\{X_{n}\right\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a Markov chain with state space $\{0,1,2, \ldots\}$. The transition probabilities are
$$
 p_{0,1}=1, \quad p_{i, i+1}+p_{i, i-1}=1, \quad p_{i, i+1}=\left(\frac{i+1}{i}\right)^{2} p_{i, i-1}, \quad i \geq 1
 $$

(1)Suppose that $X_{0}=0 .$ Find the probability that the chain never returns to state $0 .$

(2)Now suppose that the transition probabilities are
$$
  p_{0,1}=1, \quad p_{i, i+1}+p_{i, i-1}=1, \quad p_{i, i+1}=\left(\frac{i+1}{i}\right)^{\alpha} p_{i, i-1}, \quad i \geq 1
  $$
for some constant $\alpha .$ For every $\alpha \in(-\infty, \infty),$ indicate whether the chain is positive recurrent, null recurrent, or transient. Prove your conclusion.

I have a idear to get the probability that chain never returns to state 0 based on recurrence formula, but I have no idear about how to slove the complex relationship between $p_{i, i-1}$ and $p_{i, i+1}$, is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Can you explain where you got stuck or steps you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

For (1), the answer is $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$. Let $h_n=\mathbb P_n(\text{hit }0)$, so $h_0=1$ and we want $1-h_1$. Then
$$h_n=p_{n,n-1}h_{n-1}+p_{n,n+1}h_{n+1}\implies \frac{h_{n+1}-h_n}{h_n-h_{n-1}}=\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}.$$
Telescoping, we get $h_{n+1}-h_n=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}(h_1-h_0)$. So summing over $0\leq n\leq m-1$, we obtain $$h_m=1+(h_1-1)\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{k^2}.$$
As $\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{k^2}\to\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, the fact that $(h_m)_{m=0}^\infty$ is the smallest non-negative solution to this equation implies that $h_1=1-\frac{6}{\pi^2}$.

---

The chain is transient if $\alpha>1$, and recurrent if $\alpha\leq1$. Repeating the calculation above, we get
$$h_m=1+(h_1-1)\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{k^\alpha}.$$
If $\alpha\leq1$, the series diverges, so as the $h_m$ are bounded, we need $h_1=1$. This implies the chain is recurrent.

If $\alpha>1$, the series converges to some $C>0$. As above, we get $h_1=1-\frac{1}{C}<1$, so the chain is transient.

Comment: Thanks! The prove is right and useful. how about the prove of positive recurrent and null recurrent?