# Irreducible Transient Markov chain with infinite state space returns to i

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk

I have an irreducible transient Markov chain with **infinite state** space {0,1,2,...} and I am trying to find the probability that the chain never returns to the initial state (let's say state 0). For example, consider an asymmetric random walk, in which the states (starting from zero) have a different probability each, so the probability of going left $p_{i,i-1}$ is less than the probability of going right $p_{i,i+1}$, but when the step n goes to infinity, both probabilities are the same (1/2).

**How can I prove that the chain never returns to zero?**

> A state is transient if there's a nonzero probability that, starting there, that state is never visited again.

In other words: $f_{ii}=P(X_n=i\ for\ some\ n \ge 1|X_0=i)>0$ In this case $i=0$

Thank you.

Comment: *"or example, consider an asymmetric random walk, in which the states (starting from zero) have a different probability each, so the probability of going left ,−1 is less than the probability of going right ,+1, but when the step n goes to infinity, both probabilities are the same (1/2)."*... Isn't this the same as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3964181/is-this-markov-chain-recurrent-or-transient  ?  There are many specialized techniques that may be deployed... which ones are tractable for a given problem, varies considerably.

Answer (score 1):

This question is false as stated. If $p_{0,1}=1$, $p_{i,i+1}=\frac{i+1}{2i+1}$ and $p_{i,i-1}=\frac{i}{2i+1}$, then [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3964385/positive-recurrent-null-recurrent-or-transient-prove-of-0-1-markov-chain/3964655#3964655) I show that the chain is in fact recurrent.